# System.Linq.Dynamic IEnumerable OrderBy

Tags: ienumerable

```
var list = new List<stu> {
    new stu{ id=1,name="123" },
    new stu{ id=2,name="a123" },
    new stu{ id=3,name="b123" },
    new stu{ id=4,name="c123" },
    new stu{ id=5,name="d123" },
    new stu{ id=6,name="e123" },
    new stu{ id=7,name="f123" },
};

var data = list.Select("name").OrderBy("name");
```

The Select Method return IEnumerable type,then OrderBy,however throw error

**No property or field 'name' exists in type 'String'**

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a bit wonky, or at least incomplete, so I wasn't able to quite figure out what you're up to outside of this snippet. Assuming you have something like this:

```
class stu
{
    private int m_id;
    private string m_name;

    public int Id { get { return m_id; } set { m_id=value; } }
    public string Name { get { return m_name; } set { m_name=value; } }

    public stu(int id,string name)
    {
        m_id=id;
        m_name=name;
    }
}
```

It appears to me that your code wouldn't even compile on numerous fronts.  This could be because I am using an older Visual Studio.  To get this to compile, I changed the first part like so (you'll note that I mixed up the alpha order to allow you to see that the sorting actually happens):

```
var list = new List<stu> 
{
    new stu(1,"123"),
    new stu(2,"f123"),
    new stu(3,"b123"),
    new stu(4,"e123"),
    new stu(5,"d123"),
    new stu(6,"c123"),
    new stu(7,"a123"),
};
```

After that, it looks from your code as if you are expecting back a list of stu,  but are getting back a list of string.  What I would do here is order the list first, then select and get back a sorted list of strings.

```
var data = list.OrderBy(s => s.Name).Select(s => s.Name).ToList();
foreach(string str in data) { Console.WriteLine(str); }
```

If what you really want back on the select is a sorted List of stu then you would modify like so.

```
var data = list.OrderBy(s => s.Name);
foreach(stu s in data) { Console.WriteLine(s.Name); }
```

Let me know if I am missing your intent.